# Handing Over Completed Audio after Post Production

Tags: post-production, complete

Hi guys, am just reaching the final stages of Audio Post production on a short film. It will be one of my first completed jobs, and I was just wondering how do you guys complete it? So it sound good and everything is almost in place. Do I need to place Bleeps at the start/end? I'm readin David Yewdall's 'Practical Art of Motion Picture Sound" and he has alot of bits about places tones in certain places and such.

This a small production, 100% Digital. Can I just send the Audio File and let the director synch it to the video? What kind of sample rate and bit depth is recommended?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Printmaster it.

Comment: From the way his question was phrased, I think the OP might need that word defined.

Answer (score 1):

Does the reference QT you have been working to have a SMPTE leader at the heed and tail? (SMPTE Leader is the countdown to the 2 pop) - because THAT is the reason to put a 1 frame long beep on the 2 flashframe - you should always ask for it on your QTs so if there is a sync issue you can check it fast, ie sync to head pop, and check the tail pop....

When you do hand over your mix, ask if you can be there to check sync when it is synced to the final picture. You dont want to wait until it screens or is online to discover its 3f put of sync! And it can happen, eg a misconform of picture and your sound is out of sync (even though its the picture at fault)

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to start my first contribution by stating the obious but I would start by asking my client what parameters he/she wants.

As for "standard" that would be 48Khz for digital recordings. Bitrate should be 40Mbit/s.

I am just shooting from the hip thinking on what I would ask if I was the cutter/director.

As for the bleeps, yes, initial and end are useful when cutting/editing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by bitrate.  48k 16-bit runs at 705 KBps/channel, 48k 24-bit at 1152.